# Can't parse XML file on https with simplexml

Tags: php, xml, ssl, https, simplexml

I made a little piece of code in php that works well on http but when I tranfered my website on https it's not working anymore.

```
$mosaique = simplexml_load_file('https://example.com/file.xml');
```

I tried with a curl function but it's return an error.

```
$path = 'https://example.com/file.xml';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$xmlreturn = curl_exec($ch);
 if($xmlreturn === false) {
        $erreur = "--";
        return $erreur;
    }
curl_close($ch);
$mosaique = simplexml_load_string($xmlreturn, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);*
```

Do you have a way to parse xml on https ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. What do mean by doesn't work? Do you get an error, an incorrect result, or a wrong one?

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to work with HTTP secured connection, you need to enable `openssl` extension. To enable it, you will have to follow these steps:

1. Open up `php.ini` configuration file
2. Search for `extension=php_openssl.dll` in the file
3. If you have a line like `;extension=php_openssl.dll`, remove semicolon to enable it.
4. Save the file and restart your web server

Once you're done with the above steps, you could try checking it out to see if it works.